# Add two languages on static website on S3 built with bootstrap

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, amazon-s3

Is there any way I could set up the same website with two languages on S3.

I have a website xxxxx.es (in Spanish) and would like to have a language selector at the top of the navbar in order to choose the specific language. I have added the language selector with bootstrap and jquery. However, how to I then redirect to the page with my other language?

This is the website I found the language selector:

http://codepen.io/cooljockey/pen/jqRpdL

```
<select class="selectpicker" data-width="fit">
<option data-content='<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-us"></span> English'>English</option>
  <option  data-content='<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-mx"></span> Español'>Español</option>
</select>

$(function(){
$('.selectpicker').selectpicker();});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use this jQuery plugin - which I believe is [bootstrap-select](https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/) - you should focus on *change* event of the *select* element. This way if user pick some language from the drop-down list the page will reload to the exact same location with the Query String value preserved.

Here's the example HTML code...

```
 <select class="selectpicker" data-width="fit">
    <option value='en' data-content='<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-us"></span> English'>English</option>
  <option value='es' data-content='<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-mx"></span> Español'>Español</option>
</select>
```

... and the jQuery part:

```
$(function(){
    $('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
    $('.selectpicker').on('change', function(){
      document.location = $(this).val() + window.location.pathname + window.location.search;
    })
});
```

However, I'd advice you to use create a HTML + CSS drop down menu for language selection as it's a basic functionality and should work event when the JavaScript is turned off.